# Action mode close button text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I see to set the text color of the action mode "done" / "close" button. This is what I've tried:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionModeCloseButton</item>
....
<style name="ActionModeCloseButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

but is has no effect.

[image]

Note that on JB, it's enough that I make the `ActionModeCloseButton` style's parent the regular holo theme. It works fine there (without the `textColor` setting even).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the textview "Done" is only visible on large devices.
Checkout `action_mode_close_item.xml` in the Android source.
So the `android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle` only applies to the containing view and not the imageview and the textview.

Luckily, the android engineers used publicly accessible attributes to styles the childviews.

- Use `android:actionMenuTextColor` to change to textColor of the TextView.
- Use `android:actionModeCloseDrawable` to change the drawable of the ImageView

Example:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/my_close_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Below is a copy of the `action_mode_close_item.xml` in the `layout-large`-folder where you can see how the layout is build.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/action_mode_close_button"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingStart="8dip"
        style="?android:attr/actionModeCloseButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dip">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="48dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:scaleType="center"
               android:src="?android:attr/actionModeCloseDrawable" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_marginStart="4dip"
              android:layout_marginEnd="16dip"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:textColor="?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:text="@string/action_mode_done" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with actionMenuTextColor is that it will also change the color for the "normal" action bar items.

Comment: This doesn't work because the right item to change is `abs__action_mode_close_item.xml` and not `abs__action_menu_item_layout.xml`. Problem is that `abs__action_mode_close_item.xml` doesn't provide a text color :( you could easily fix it for ABS but that's only working for Androids previous to 4.0. Sorry to say this ...

Answer (score 0):

Since the layout for the action mode close button doesn't provide a color attribute for the text view, there is no way to set this color in a custom theme. Instead the only ay I found was to overwrite the text color  in the `onPrepareActionMode()` method of my derived `ActionMode` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... none) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void none) {
            if (activity != null) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) activity
                            .findViewById(R.id.abs__action_mode_close_button);

                if (layout == null) {
                    int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                                      "action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");
                    layout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(id);
                }

                if (layout != null && layout.getChildCount() > 1) {
                    TextView label = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(1);
                    if (label != null) label.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    }.execute();

    return false;
}
```

Worked with two devices pre and post Android 4.0.

Comment: Careful, if a version of android doesn't have a TextView at position 1 your code will blow up on that device. I would do an instanceOf check on that before casting it.